# Convert JavaScript regular expression to PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have following JavaScript code with regular expression which is working as expected.

```
var re =  /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[\w~@#$%^&*+=`|<>'{}:;,!.?/\\"()\[\]-]{10,99}$/;
    return re.test(value);
```

When I tried to convert this to PHP I am getting the following error.

> Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '&'

I have tried following PHP code

```
$pass = 'avbbc';
if(!preg_match( '^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[\w~@#$%^&*+=`|<>\'{}:;,!.?\\"()\[\]-]{10,99}$', $pass )){
    echo "error";
}else{
    echo "success";
}
```

Comment: Use ``preg_match( '/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[\w~@#$%^&*+=`|<>\'{}:;,!.?\\\\"()[\]-]{10,99}$/', $pass )``

Comment: You didn't include the delimiters in the regex. (e.g. the `/` at start and end)

Comment: Yeah, use delimiters and make sure to match a backslash with 4 ``\``s.